# converting byte array to CryptographicKey

Tags: encryption, unity-game-engine, win-universal-app

**Background:**

I am building my Unity app for Windows Store Universal 10. It's already live for Android and iOS as well as WP8.

My app sends encrypted session data back to the server for processing.  Currently it's using the AesManaged() library like so:

```
        using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            Aes aes = new AesManaged();
            aes.BlockSize = 128;
            aes.KeySize = 256;
            aes.Key = keyBytes;
...
            using (CryptoStream cs = new CryptoStream(memoryStream, encryptor, CryptoStreamMode.Write))
            {
                cs.Write(plainTextBytes, 0, plainTextBytes.Length);
                cs.FlushFinalBlock();
                byte[] cipherTextBytes = memoryStream.ToArray();
                cs.Close();
                return cipherTextBytes;
            }
        }
```

The key I am using is using for Aes.Key is a custom method which returns a byte[]:

```
 public static byte[] getKeyBytes(string pApiKey, string pSecret)
```

According to several articles,

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/52080335-0016-4370-889b-3afe0c0dcb7a/how-to-do-simple-aes-encryptiondecryption-in-metro

http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/aesmanaged-wp8-1-the-type-or-namespace-name-aesmanaged-could-not-be-found.376732/

And my Unity Build errors, the AesManaged libraries do not work when targeting Windows Store and I need to instead be using the updated encryption libraries (Windows.Security.Cryptography.Core):

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.security.cryptography.core.symmetrickeyalgorithmprovider.aspx

This seems straightforward, except that the new encryption method:

```
 CryptographicEngine.Encrypt(key, buffMsg, iv);
```

Takes a CryptographicKey object as an argument instead of a byte[] (which my keys currently are)

**Question:**

How does one go about casting a byte[] to a CryptographicKey object so I can use the new required encryption methods with my existing keys?

When I try:

```
CryptographicKey key = new CryptographicKey(pKeyByteArray);
```

I get:

```
error CS1729: 'CryptographicKey' does not contain a constructor that takes 1 arguments
```

Note: there appears to be a CryptographicKey in System.Web.Security.Cryptography which does this:

http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System.Web/Security/Cryptography/CryptographicKey.cs,58f5cc896110a437,references

But this appears to not available to Windows Store builds.

Comment: Why not just use TLS?

Comment: @pvg, do you mean not doing any encryption logic in the application and use a TLS secured connection to send my raw data? This is certainly an option, but 1) changing the server environment is currently out of scope at the moment 2) I recall some older android devices not having full 1.2 support but stepping down to 1 or SSL3 or worse...But thanks, will look into it!

Comment: It's worth checking out because any version of SSL will provide better security than the sort of thing you're proposing which looks like just like AES in ECB mode, beside keeping your code a lot simpler.

Comment: @Stanley Did my solution work?

Comment: looking into it, might get me on the right track,... but i'm not trying to generate public keys.  I already have keys stored as byte[] and trying to use them with the new CryptographicEngine.Encrypt() method

Comment: @Stanley I know. That's what I did from line **5 to 7**. Forgot about other codes. I know you wanted to create an instance of `CryptographicKey` with your key. Look at the code. `pKeyByteArray` is the byte of the key. You must convert it to string then to` AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider`  and then create `CryptographicKey` instance with `AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider`.This should work. Forget about the rest of the code after line 7. Did that work or not?

Answer (score 0):

I wasn't able to test the code below but I modified it to work with your byte array.

```
    byte[] pKeyByteArray;
    uint keyLength = 512; //512, 1024, 2048, or 4096 bits
    pKeyByteArray = new byte[50];

    string strAsymmetricAlgName = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(pKeyByteArray);
    AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider objAlgProv = AsymmetricKeyAlgorithmProvider.OpenAlgorithm(strAsymmetricAlgName);
    CryptographicKey keyPair = objAlgProv.CreateKeyPair(keyLength);

    // Export the public key to a buffer for use by others.
    IBuffer buffPublicKey = keyPair.ExportPublicKey();


    CryptographicKeyApp.buffKeyPair = keyPair.Export();

    // Retrieve the size of the key pair.
    UInt32 lengthKeyPair = keyPair.KeySize;

    // Do something with your the public key.
   buffPublicKey........
```